# Installing db-mysql

Tags: mysql, node.js, express, mamp

I just started getting into node.js and want to use node.js together with my existing PHP/MySQL stack running on MAMP.

**Problem:** My existing data are already in the MySQL database that starts with MAMP, and I want to access them from node.js. I have decided on using `db-mysql` driver and so to install it, I specified my `MYSQL_CONFIG` environment by typing in the terminal

1. `export MYSQL_CONFIG=/Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config`
2. npm install db-mysql

Then comes the error messages:

```
> db-mysql@0.7.6 install /Users/x/mywebsite/node_modules/db-mysql
> node-waf configure build

Checking for program g++ or c++          : /usr/bin/g++ 
Checking for program cpp                 : /usr/bin/cpp 
Checking for program ar                  : /usr/bin/ar 
Checking for program ranlib              : /usr/bin/ranlib 
Checking for g++                         : ok  
Checking for node path                   : not found 
Checking for node prefix                 : ok /usr/local 
Checking for program mysql_config        : /Applications/MAMP/Library/bin/mysql_config 
Checking for library mysqlclient_r       : Missing libmysqlclient_r 
'configure' finished successfully (0.571s)
Waf: Entering directory `/Users/x/mywebsite/node_modules/db-mysql/build'
[ 1/12] cxx: lib/node-db/binding.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/binding_1.o
[ 2/12] cxx: lib/node-db/connection.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/connection_1.o
[ 3/12] cxx: lib/node-db/events.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/events_1.o
[ 4/12] cxx: lib/node-db/exception.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/exception_1.o
[ 5/12] cxx: lib/node-db/query.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/query_1.o
[ 6/12] cxx: lib/node-db/result.cc -> build/Release/lib/node-db/result_1.o
[ 7/12] cxx: src/connection.cc -> build/Release/src/connection_1.o
In file included from ../src/connection.cc:2:
../src/./connection.h:5:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../src/./connection.h:8,
                 from ../src/connection.cc:2:
../src/././result.h:16: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../src/././result.h:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ with no type
../src/././result.h:28: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../src/././result.h:54: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/././result.h:54: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/././result.h:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_RES’ with no type
../src/././result.h:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ../src/connection.cc:2:
../src/./connection.h:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/./connection.h:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/connection.cc: In constructor ‘node_db_mysql::Connection::Connection()’:
../src/connection.cc:11: error: class ‘node_db_mysql::Connection’ does not have any field named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual bool node_db_mysql::Connection::isAlive(bool)’:
../src/connection.cc:57: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:57: error: ‘mysql_ping’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual void node_db_mysql::Connection::open()’:
../src/connection.cc:65: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:65: error: ‘mysql_init’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:66: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:71: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:71: error: ‘MYSQL_SET_CHARSET_NAME’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:71: error: ‘mysql_options’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:75: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:75: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_COMPRESS’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:75: error: ‘mysql_options’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:79: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:79: error: ‘MYSQL_INIT_COMMAND’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:79: error: ‘mysql_options’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:83: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
[ 8/12] cxx: src/mysql.cc -> build/Release/src/mysql_1.o
../src/connection.cc:83: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_READ_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:83: error: ‘mysql_options’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:90: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:90: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_SSL_VERIFY_SERVER_CERT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:90: error: ‘mysql_options’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:93: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:93: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_CONNECT_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:97: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:97: error: ‘MYSQL_OPT_WRITE_TIMEOUT’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:101: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:108: error: ‘mysql_real_connect’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:116: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:116: error: ‘mysql_error’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual void node_db_mysql::Connection::close()’:
../src/connection.cc:122: error: ‘class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:122: error: ‘mysql_close’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual std::string node_db_mysql::Connection::escape(const std::string&) const’:
../src/connection.cc:133: error: ‘const class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:133: error: ‘mysql_real_escape_string’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual std::string node_db_mysql::Connection::version() const’:
../src/connection.cc:141: error: ‘const class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:141: error: ‘mysql_get_server_info’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc: In member function ‘virtual node_db::Result* node_db_mysql::Connection::query(const std::string&) const’:
../src/connection.cc:150: error: ‘const class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:150: error: ‘mysql_real_query’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:151: error: ‘const class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
../src/connection.cc:151: error: ‘mysql_error’ was not declared in this scope
../src/connection.cc:154: error: ‘const class node_db_mysql::Connection’ has no member named ‘connection’
In file included from ../src/./mysql.h:7,
                 from ../src/mysql.cc:2:
../src/././connection.h:5:19: error: mysql.h: No such file or directory
In file included from ../src/././connection.h:8,
                 from ../src/./mysql.h:7,
                 from ../src/mysql.cc:2:
../src/./././result.h:16: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
../src/./././result.h:16: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_FIELD’ with no type
../src/./././result.h:28: error: expected `)' before ‘*’ token
../src/./././result.h:54: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/./././result.h:54: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
../src/./././result.h:55: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL_RES’ with no type
../src/./././result.h:55: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
In file included from ../src/./mysql.h:7,
                 from ../src/mysql.cc:2:
../src/././connection.h:43: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘MYSQL’ with no type
../src/././connection.h:43: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
Waf: Leaving directory `/Users/x/mywebsite/node_modules/db-mysql/build'
Build failed:
 -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx connection.cc -> connection_1.o}
 -> task failed (err #1): 
    {task: cxx mysql.cc -> mysql_1.o}
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6 Error: db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6 `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6     at ChildProcess.<anonymous> (/usr/local/lib/node_modules/npm/lib/utils/exec.js:49:20)
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6     at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:70:17)
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6     at maybeExit (child_process.js:359:16)
npm ERR! error installing db-mysql@0.7.6     at Process.onexit (child_process.js:395:5)

> db-mysql@0.7.6 preuninstall /Users/x/mywebsite/node_modules/db-mysql
> rm -rf build/*

npm ERR! db-mysql@0.7.6 install: `node-waf configure build`
npm ERR! `sh "-c" "node-waf configure build"` failed with 1
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Failed at the db-mysql@0.7.6 install script.
npm ERR! This is most likely a problem with the db-mysql package,
npm ERR! not with npm itself.
npm ERR! Tell the author that this fails on your system:
npm ERR!     node-waf configure build
npm ERR! You can get their info via:
npm ERR!     npm owner ls db-mysql
npm ERR! There is likely additional logging output above.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! System Darwin 11.2.0
npm ERR! command "node" "/usr/local/bin/npm" "install" "db-mysql"
npm ERR! cwd /Users/x/mywebsite
npm ERR! node -v v0.6.2
npm ERR! npm -v 1.0.106
npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Additional logging details can be found in:
npm ERR!     /Users/x/mywebsite/npm-debug.log
npm not ok
```

Where did I go wrong? Or is there a better way to setup `db-mysql`?

Comment: node-mysql worked, but not db-mysql...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Went with `node-mysql` works great